# How to justify ul list without blank space and text hidden?

Tags: css, flexbox, justify

I have an UL that I want to justify.

```
    #main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
list-style:none;
}

#main li {
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: 1;
text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="main">
  <li style="background-color:red;">RED</li>
  <li style="background-color:blue;">BLUE</li>  
  <li style="background-color:green;">Green div with more content.</li>
</ul>
```

[Take a look at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5tjbw6j/)

but right now there is blank space on the beginning and text is cut/hidden on the last element.
How to stop cutting text in last green li element? I am working on Bootstrap nav-justified replacement for Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to the `ul` element.

See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5tjbw6j/1/):

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ach! Right! forgot about that. Thx!

Comment: @RelesRepie, no prob, glad it worked. May I suggest marking this answer as accepted if it solved your problem?